# Creating Document Libraries Using WebDav Interface

Tags: document-library, folder, metadata, webdav

I am currently developing an app that uses the WebDav HTTP protocol to communicate and handle interactions with a Sharepoint site. While I can use a MKCOL request to create directories within a SharePoint site, I'd like to be able to create Document Libraries as well.

What sort of meta-data do I need to add to a folder I've created for it to be recognized as Document Library, or is it even possible using WebDav to accomplish something like this? When comparing one of my own folders against a Document Library using a PROPFIND call I see no obvious differences in terms of the tags that are used.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm super stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out using Sharepoint 2010, there is no way to create root level libraries using the standard WebDAV HTTP API that is standardized. C#.NET appears to have libraries built for handling this, so use C# if at all possible.